# I have downloaded silverlight3 SDK and silverlight toolkit. Now How to configure this with Visual studio 2008?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I have Downloaded Silverlight3 ToolKit and Silverlight SDK. Now how to configure it with visual studio 2008? VS2008 is not showing option for creating silverlight application.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have installed VS2008SP1. Now I am able to create silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

Heh... I think after you do the install and such, it should show as a new project type.  I have just begun experimenting with the SL3 SDK and just had to install it against VS.Net 2008 SP1, and I was good to go.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have installed VS2008SP1. Now I am able to create silverlight application

Answer (score 0):

Seems everyone gets confused about this ;-)

You need the [Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=143571) package.  It contains the developer runtime (for debugging), the SDK (for building and basic controls), and the Visual Studio integration package.

The Silverlight Toolkit is a separate package containing a larger set of controls that don't ship in the SDK (partly because they're less mature, and partly because the Toolkit updates more often).